# What stack/programming language is Azure written in?

Tags: azure, stack

I am very impressed with the `Azure` dashboard UI and I can't figure out what stack/languages/etc it's made with? It works in all browsers, can copy/paste in all browsers and knows connection state. It does not look like `Flash` or `Silverlight`... or is it? Please help me figure this out.

Comment: Serj - as curious as you might be... StackOverflow isn't going to be the place for this. It's not a programming question. And this isn't the place for a product team to discuss their implementation details. And as far as Flash or Silverlight: You can figure that out by yourself with a simple right-click in the browser.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The Azure portal is written in TypeScript and uses jQuery, KnockoutJS, Q, RequireJS, and Less (among a few other libraries). There's a thin ASP.NET Web API layer on the back-end, but most calls go directly to back-end services, like Azure Resource Manager (ARM).

Comment: I believe it uses raw JavaScript. The classic portal (manage.windowsazure.com) used Flash for this, but we tried to avoid that.

Comment: I do not believe that raw Javascript allows you to do Copy/Paste as a security precaution... so if you paste some code samples of how it is done, that would be amazing!

Comment: @SerjSagan, starting 2015, browsers can copy to the clipboard with JavaScript: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/400212/how-do-i-copy-to-the-clipboard-in-javascript